# Fetching the raw MIME result of a Stored Message

Tags: php, mailgun

In the [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#retrieving-stored-messages) for retrieving the raw MIME result from stored messages states that only a header `Accept` needs to be set with the value: `message/rfc2822`

However the output remains the same with or without the header.

The reason I need the raw MIME result is due to using a suite specific MIME decoder that's required in order to handle emails within the suite.

My code is as follows:

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.mailgun.net/v2/domains/$MAILGUN_DOMAIN/messages/WyIxMzZjMTQzN2NkIiwgWyI4ZTc3ZGM1Yi00ODAyLTQxMGQtYTI3ZC03ZjczZTVmODgzYWEiXSwgIm1haWxndW4iLCAib2xkY29rZSJd");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:$MAILGUN_API_KEY");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept' => 'message/rfc2822'));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump(json_decode($result));
} catch ( \Exception $e ) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance